# CustomValidator not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation, customvalidator

I have a CustomValidator that checks if text entered in textboxes matches certain fields in a database. This was all working great before, but I have modified my page quite a bit since then and it is no longer working. I didn't think I changed anything that would affect this, but apparently I did. All my other validators (required field validators) are working correctly, but my CustomValidator isn't responding.

So anyway, here is my code:

CustomValidator:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCoursePrefix" ErrorMessage="Course number is already taken."></asp:CustomValidator>
```

VB codebehind:

```
Protected Sub CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(ByVal source As Object, ByVal args As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles CustomValidator1.ServerValidate

    'Checking for duplicate course numbers

    'get values
    Dim checkPrefix = txtCoursePrefix.Text
    Dim checkNum = txtCourseNum.Text

    'db connectivity
    Dim myConn As New OleDbConnection
    myConn.ConnectionString = AccessDataSource2.ConnectionString
    myConn.Open()

    'select records
    Dim mySelect As New OleDbCommand("SELECT 1 FROM tableCourse WHERE prefix=? AND course_number=?", myConn)
    mySelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkPrefix", checkPrefix)
    mySelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkNum", checkNum)

    'execute(Command)
    Dim myValue = mySelect.ExecuteScalar()

    'check if record exists
    If myValue IsNot Nothing Then
        CustomValidator1.SetFocusOnError = True
        args.IsValid = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Everything is working up until CustomValidator1.SetFocusOnError = True and args.IsValid = False. I have tested the If statement and it's working correctly, it returns true and anything else I put inside of it executes.

Comment: Your Code seems to be OK, Problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking... no idea what could be interfering though.

Comment: Have you set a validation group on your form? If so, you'll need to add the `validationgroup` attribute to your `<asp:customvalidator>` tag.

Comment: No, I don't have a validation group... it can work without one though, right?

Answer (score 8):

Things you should know when using customvalidators:

If you are validating using a `ValidationGroup`, don't forget to add it to your `CustomValidator`.

Set the `ControlToValidate` property.

A `CustomValidator` control never fires when the `ControlToValidate` control is empty unless you set `ValidateEmptyText=true`.

When using `ClientValidationFunction="customClientValidationFunction"` use the following signature:

```
function customClientValidationFunction(sender, arguments) {
   arguments.IsValid = true; //validation goes here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should set the property `ValidateEmptyText="true"` on the `CustomValidator`. The client and server functions will always be called in that case.

It solved the problem for me.

Comment: Good one i was so much confused for this simple thing i googled and find your answer

Answer (score 1):

If the handler is getting called, and you're successfully setting the args.IsValid to false, then what that does is it sets Page.IsValid to false.  But unfortunately, that doesn't stop the form from being sumbitted.  What you need to do is check that Page.IsValid property in your code that handles your form submit, like in the submit button handler.

So in addition to the code you posted, which sounds like it is working correctly, make sure that you have something like this for your submit handler (C# example):

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsValid)
    {
        // by simply returning, the error message for the CustomValidator will be displayed
        return;
    }
    // do processing for valid form here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate"

like an example and it will work....

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCoursePrefix" ErrorMessage="Course number is already taken." OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Gaurav Agrawal

Comment: Didn't work... because it's already getting called, since I have "Handles CustomValidator1.ServerValidate" in my code behind.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, put validation group on validators and the button. If that too doesnt work, put OnClientClick='CheckValidate();' and declare the function which will call page_clientvalidate method along with the parameter.. validation group. This would surely work. If that is not working put debugger in the javascript method and debug the same